# IIS 7.5 and ASP MVC startup performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

i've followed this tutorial to speed up the first time the asp mvc web app load.

[Auto Starting Websites on IIS 7.5](http://www.schwammysays.net/auto-starting-websites-on-iis-7-5/)

Anyway i haven't see any better performance. How can i speed up the asp mvc in iis 7.5? Any solutions?

Comment: I don't think there is a way via configuration to reduce the load times for the "first load" of an webapplication. You could use more hardware. I can imagine a SSD would speed up the load process. The hints from your link are the describing the how to keep the process alive in order to reduce the amount of application loading

Comment: If it's the 1st load that's the issue, you could set up a CRON job to hit the homepage of the site at a given interval (e.g. every 15/20mins) and this will keep it `alive`.